# What is a log file and how can we create a log file in android?

Tags: android

I don't have any knowledge about the log files. what are log files and how can we create a log in android? Please help me out in creating log files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android will generate it's own log file whenever you run app then log will file is generated.
just go to eclipse=>window=>show view=>other=>Android=>Log Cat(select) that now you can see the logs which are generated.

Comment: Ok! but how can I log errors into this log file for my application?

Comment: you can't log error into log file whenever an error is occoured it will be there in log file & that will appear in red color so you can identify the errors in your app.

Comment: I want to generate my own file in which i can log the errors.How can I generate my own log file?

Comment: you can't generate your own log file.

Comment: okk..if I want explicitly to log errors to the log file how can we do that?

Comment: you can mail me what u want on sumant4943@gmail.com .i will try to give sol to it. also explicitly we can't add errors to log file..

Comment: The log file is ther by default in all the applications??

Comment: Yes it is there whenever you run your app it will get info for that app

Answer (score 3):

As others mentioned you can use the logcat to look at the logs.  If you want your own logs, you need print to the Logger.  Use [android.Util.Log](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log.html) for that.

Answer (score 2):

eclipse=>window=>show view=>other=>Android=>Log Cat(select)

Yes the above answer is correct, once you choose that above option one window will be added to your prospective beside console. and when ever you run your application in the emulator the **LOGCAT** window will show all the debug and error related statements in it..  It is very useful to work with android.

You can also collect log in the real android device also using **Log Collecter** free application which is available in android market.. Using this application you can trace out the problems in your application.

Later on you can send collected log to email also through which you can identify problem in the real device.

Comment: The log file is ther by default in all the applications??